# How to parse through the file and retrieve certain words

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, awk, sed

A file has text something like this:

```
 32 host1       dock0:network__cps-spr-adapter,network__cps-ocs-adapter
 33 host2       dock2:custom-work__ccep-sep-adapter
 34 host3       dock2:custom-work__gmsa-host,dock1:custom-work2
 35 host4       dock2:eodprvg__subsactivity
```

I want to parse each line of the file and want to retrieve the words that have prefix dock0/dock1/dock2

In the above text, my expected output is:

```
dock0:network__cps-spr-adapter
dock2:custom-work__ccep-sep-adapter
dock2:custom-work__gmsa-host
dock1:custom-work2
dock2:eodprvg__subsactivity
```

Comment: Read [ask] then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{ print $3; }' your-input-file | awk -F, '{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ /^dock[0-2]:/) print $i;
  }
}'
```

Produces the following output given your input.

```
dock0:network__cps-spr-adapter
dock2:custom-work__ccep-sep-adapter
dock2:custom-work__gmsa-host
dock1:custom-work2
dock2:eodprvg__subsactivity
```

Update:

Variant inspired by a suggestion from @Cyrus that avoids the pipeline and incorporates a request from @sri-k to also match `dock:`

```
awk -F'[ ,]+' '{
  for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
    if ($i ~ /^dock[0-2]?:/) print $i;
  }
}' your-input-file
```

Comment: no, because if you look at the data $3 is a comma separated list of prefixed words, and your example doesn't give the output requested.

Comment: @AustinFrance: works very well. I've just realized there are some rows with the text "dock:platform-xyz",  how do I accommodate this? The above script works perfectly fine for the ones starting with dock0/dock1/doc2.

Comment: Change /^dock[0-2]:/ to /^dock:[0-2]?:/ which says match number 0 - 2 for 0 or 1 times.  So it will specifically match dock: dock0: dock1: dock2: and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @AustinFrance, it did work.

Comment: @Cyrus still doesn't generate the required output.  It ignores dock1:custom-work2.  Using -F'[ ,]+' my example can be improved to drop the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Simply get the third field using awk:

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\n/!s/[^ ,]\+/\n&\n/g;/^dock[012]/P;D' file
```

Split up lines into single words and print only those words that begin `dock` followed by `0`,`1` or `2`.

Comment: Thanks potong, I did try with this, I expected it would print the output on the console, but it did not.  no output is seen.